# Service interface is not visible in SPROXY

Tags: web-services, abap, sap-erp, sap-pi, sap-xi

I had generated a service interface in IR (PI 7.1) but when checking in ECC i couldnt see it in sproxy. The 'G' rfc seems okay and all basic setting and connections seem to be fine. Need some help to fix this please?

I had included my service interface into a namespace http://sap.com/xi/HR within the SCV SAP HR 6.04 where there were some already created service interface visible in SPROXY but not the one I just created.

Just want to be sure, do I need to complete the configuration for the service interface to be visible in SPROXY? or just activating the IR should work?

Comment: You do not have to complete the interface. Only the service interface should be activated. You can check if the SLD connection is running properly (trx. SLDCHECK). Is this the first service interface which is used from the SAP system? Or are there other (working) service interface used from this system?

Comment: thkx Koen. it seems adding a service interface in sap.com namespace doesnt show the interface name in sproxy. working fine with a z namespace